# Uploading images to amazon s3 using boto3 from django

Tags: django, python-3.x, boto3

import boto3

from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

BUCKET_NAME = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-dev-bkt'

data = open('/home/kuliza270/Desktop/workspace/hdfc-csrm-backend/webapp/statics/img/headerLogoNew.jpg', 'rb')

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',

```
aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
```

)

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='logo.jpg', Body=data)

print ("Done")

Comment: getting error:   Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"

Comment: I think test-dev-bkt is your bucket name. Not the url of s3

Comment: if i am using just name of bucket getting this error----------The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The value in BUCKET_NAME is not correct, according to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) your bucket name is test-dev-bkt:

> In a path-style URL, the bucket name is not part of the domain (unless
>   you use a Region-specific endpoint). For example:
>
> ```
> US East (N. Virginia) Region endpoint, http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket
>
> Region-specific endpoint, http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket
> ```
>
> In a path-style URL, the endpoint you use must match the Region in
>   which the bucket resides. For example, if your bucket is in the South
>   America (São Paulo) Region, you must use the
>   http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket endpoint. If your bucket is
>   in the US East (N. Virginia) Region, you must use the
>   http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket endpoint.

Comment: if i am using just name of bucket getting this error----------The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint